# Is there any option to set a field in UVM RAL model register by its index?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have the following REG_CLOCK (uvm ral model) - uart_ral_model.

One of the registers is named `uart_intrpt`.

I have to set '1' to fields which I indicate by index.

Is there any option to set a field in a UVM RAL register model by its index?

Comment: “By its index” by it bit position MSB/LSB   , or by some other measure?

Comment: by bit offset of the field within a register

Comment: Have you already set up the uvm_reg_fields for this uvm_reg? Does the `1` you want to set correspond to the entirety of one of the fields?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to set bit fields is to use the field name and one of the `uvm_reg_field` class access methods: `set`, `write`, etc.  Refer to the [UVM Class Reference](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1d/html/index.html) documentation.  The advantage to this is that you operate *only* on the field of interest within the register without concerning yourself about the other fields in the register (if any).

You could also set a field by modifying the register as a whole.  However, if you are targeting only a single field within the register, you may need to do more work.  The general approach is a "read-modify-write":

1. Read the register and store its data value in a local variable.
2. Modify only the bits corresponding to the field of interest in the variable, keeping all other bits (fields) at their current values.
3. Write the new value of the variable to the register.

The disadvantage of this approach is that you need to know the bit offset of the field within the register and also the field width.  The the `uvm_reg_field` class introspection methods help out with this: `get_lsb_pos` and `get_n_bits`.

Using the field name abstracts those details away from you.